# string.trim() not functional?

Tags: java, string, eclipse-juno

It may look a Stupid question, but It is giving wrong output !!

The trim() is supposed to delete the 'space' or 'new line' character at the beginning or end of the String, but it isn't working.

```
String str=str.getText().toString();
str.trim();
if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("STRING"))
    mytextview.setText("True");
else
    mytextview.setText("False");
```

If I'm Entering ---> 
                              **"        STRING          "**
(With many spaces ),
I am getting **False** as the Answer .... I'm using Eclipse Juno for my Androing Project, are there any exceptions ? 
Please Help.

Comment: A `String` in java is immutable. It can not be modified. `trim()` returns a new `String`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String str=str.getText().toString();
str.trim();
```

should be:

```
String str=str.getText().toString();
str = str.trim();
```

`Strings` are immutable in Java. An operation like `trim()` creates a new String.

Comment: @user2525485: Looks like Nambari beat all of us to the answer. The best way for this site to help others is select an answer. That way if others view the question they have a clear "correct" answer. You can mark the selected answer by clicking on the checkmark next to Nambari's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are not storing the output of `str.trim()`.  It does not modify the original `String`; rather, it generates a new, separate one.

You can store it back into the original by using `str = str.trim()`.

Answer (score 1):

`String.trim()` returns the resulting trimmed string.

You need to do `str = str.trim();`

Answer (score 1):

The trim method returns a copy of the string. Change the second line to be:

```
str = str.trim();
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 String str=str.getText().toString().trim();
```